# svn: checking out tailor-made directory structure at client-side

Tags: svn

I'd like to know whether there's support for the following wish:  At client-side, i.e., in my work-directory space, I don't want to have a one-to-one work-copy from the directory tree (resp. a sub-tree) as is found on the server. Instead, I'd like to have a particular view such as

```
take directory1 from the repos, check it out here under ./mydirectory1
take directory2 from the repos, check it out here under ./mydirectory2
```

Things like that. I think the "module" feature of CVS was/is able to do that.

Is there something similar in svn?

PS: I am aware of the :externals: property. But that's not what I want, because that requires that the individual client/user has to do the right thing, setting the externals correct. I prefer that this configuration is done only once, and so the users get the same view on the checked-out stuff.

PPS: I could imagine that symbolic links would achieve similar effect to the thing I want
     as long as everything is within the same repository/work-directory since then
     the linking can use relative paths. (I don't know though whether symbolic links
     are a robust solution across different file systems)

Answer (score 1):

From the repository, you can't dictate where/how users check out their working copies. The closest you can get is to create a "meta" directory which has no items in it, but is populated via `svn:externals`. If you can't trust your users to use the system properly, you need to train your users better, get new users, or install hook scripts to inspect commits & reject any that are non-conformant.

Symlinks will not work for any clients using Windows.

Comment: ok, thanks. That's what I feared. Actually, it's then a feature which I somehow miss (compared to CVS for instance). It's perhaps not so much that one does not trust the users, it's about avoiding duplicating work ("everyone please configure it the following way, and PLEASE, don't be smart and try funny things") and just making _sure_ that everyone's on the same page (without exposing them to the details of how that's achieved). Anyway, a negative answer allows me to not look further in the later sections of the manual....

Answer (score 0):

Externals *are* the right way to achieve what you want. You need to add a root directory to your repository:

```
svn mkdir file:/path/to/repos/root
```

Then check it out:

```
svn co file:/path/to/repos/root root -m"Creating root directory"
```

Add proper external definitions:

```
svn propedit svn:externals root
```

This will open your editor on an empty file in which you should add:

```
mydirectory1 file:/path/to/repos/directory1
mydirectory2 file:/path/to/repos/directory2
```

Commit your changes:

```
svn commit root -m"Added externals to root"
```

If now you run update:

```
svn update root
```

the contents of `directory1` and `directory2` should be checked out as `root/mydirectory1` and `root/mydirectory2`.

Ask your users to check out `file:/path/to/repos/root` and they'll also get your additional directory.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, that was what I was looking for; obviously I had a wrong impression what :externals can do, I thought it is only individually per one client/work directory.